# "Iterative" Window function on subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, window, subset

I am looking for a way to create the column `'min_value'` from the dataframe `df` below. For each row i, we subset from the entire dataframe all the records that correspond to the grouping `['Date_A', 'Date_B']` of the row i and having the condition `'Advance'` less than `'Advance'` of row i, and finally we pick the minimum of the column `'Amount'` from this subset to set `'min_value'` for the row i:

Initial dataframe:

```
dates_A = ['2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2018-1-25','2018-1-25','2018-1-25']
Date_A = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_A]
dates_B = ['2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-2-1','2018-2-1','2018-2-1']
Date_B = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_B]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_A':Date_A,
       'Date_B':Date_B,        
       'Advance' : [10,103,200,5,8,150],
       'Amount' : [180,220,200,230,220,240]})

df  = df [['Date_A', 'Date_B', 'Advance', 'Amount']]
df
```

Desired output:

```
dates_A = ['2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2018-1-25','2018-1-25','2018-1-25']
Date_A = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_A]
dates_B = ['2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-2-1','2018-2-1','2018-2-1']
Date_B = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_B]
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Date_A':Date_A,
       'Date_B':Date_B,        
       'Advance' : [10,103,200,5,8,150],
       'Amount' : [180,220,200,230,220,240],
       'min_value': [180,180,180,230,230,220] })

df_out  = df_out [['Date_A', 'Date_B', 'Advance', 'Amount','min_value']]
df_out
```

I wrote the following loop that I think would do the job but it is much too long to run, I guess there must be much more efficient ways to accomplish this.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    date1=df['Date_A'][i] #select the date A of the row i 
    date2=df['Date_B'][i] #select the date B of the row i 
    advance= df['Advance'][i] #select the advance of the row i 
    df.loc[i,'min_value'] = df[df['Date_A']==date1][df['Date_B']==date2][df['Advance']<advance]['Amount'].min()  # subset the entire dataframe to meet dates and advance conditions
    df.loc[df['min_value'].isnull(),'min_value']=df['Amount'] # for the smallest advance value, ste min=to its own amount
df
```

I hope it is clear enough, thanks for your help.

Improvement question
Thanks a lot for the answer. For the last part, the NA rows, I'd like to replace the amount of the row by the overall amount of the Date_A,Date_B,advance grouping so that I have the overall minimum of the last day before date_A

Improvement desired output (two recodrs for the smallest advance value)

```
dates_A = ['2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2017-12-25','2017-12-25']
Date_A = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_A]
dates_B = ['2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-1-1','2018-1-1']
Date_B = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in dates_B]

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Date_A':Date_A,
       'Date_B':Date_B,        
       'Advance' : [5,8,150,5],
       'Amount' : [230,220,240,225],
       'min_value': [225,230,220,225] })

df_out  = df_out [['Date_A', 'Date_B', 'Advance', 'Amount','min_value']]
df_out
```

Thanks

Comment: You should include your desired output in your post as well. I am unclear what your `Advance` condition is exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on `'Date_A'` and `'Date_B'` after sorting the value by `'Advance'` and `apply` the function [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummin.html) and `shift` to the column `'Amount'`. Then use `fillna` with the value from the column `'Amount'`, such as:

```
df['min_value'] = (df.sort_values('Advance').groupby(['Date_A','Date_B'])['Amount']
                      .apply(lambda ser_g: ser_g.cummin().shift()).fillna(df['Amount']))
```

and you get:

```
       Date_A      Date_B  Advance  Amount  min_value 
0  2017-12-25  2018-01-01       10     180      180.0      
1  2017-12-25  2018-01-01      103     220      180.0 
2  2017-12-25  2018-01-01      200     200      180.0 
3  2018-01-25  2018-02-01        5     230      230.0 
4  2018-01-25  2018-02-01        8     220      230.0 
5  2018-01-25  2018-02-01      150     240      220.0
```

Comment: This is the best solution. +1

Comment: The outcome is great, I just added a question to slightly improve it on the main question

Comment: @mo29 that should be posted as a separate question since it warrants a different solution